# trying to post $file but its saying not set

Tags: php, multiple-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple videos, through form but my php file is saying its not set

i have increased my max upload to 500m and i included enctype but it still does the same thing

html

```
<form action="apps/course/uploadvideo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input style="display: none" type="file" name="videos[]" id='video1' multiple="multiple" accept=".mov,.mp4" />
  <input style="display: none" type="file" name="videos[]" id='video2' multiple="multiple" accept=".mov,.mp4" />
  <input style="display: none" type="file" name="videos[]" id='video3' multiple="multiple" accept=".mov,.mp4" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Videos" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
</form>
```

php code

```
if(isset($_FILES['videos'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['videos']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['videos']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['videos']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['videos']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['videos']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], 
                              "../../../../upload/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

after var dumping it outputs this
array (size=0)
  empty

I expect it to move to the required folder

Comment: Why do you have 3 different inputs when they have the `multiple` attribute? That allows you to use a single input to upload multiple files.

Comment: Also don't forget to increase your post size in ini file too.

Comment: Even after removing the multiple it still dosent work , i also increased my post size it also dosen't work

Comment: Have you tried performing a `var_dump()` or some equivalent of your `$_FILES` data? It might help to ensure that you're actually receiving data.

Comment: it comes out empty after var dumping it

Comment: Add your `var_dump` to the question so we can see how you went about it.

Comment: i have just added it tot the question @EternalHour

Comment: @lazysensei - I meant add it into the code portion. You put it before anything else in `uploadvideo.php`?

Comment: We need to see the actual `var_dump` call. Are you doing `var_dump($_FILES)` or `var_dump($_FILES['videos'])`? The distinction is important. We want the former, not the latter, so we need to know which you've tried.